# ionic 2 datetime-local minute step 30 min

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I have a datetime-local input box in my ionic 2 app but I want to show the minutes in 30 min interval only, that is only 0 or 30 (like 9.00 or 9.30). I read about steps but could not find for minutes. Is there a way to achieve it ?

Comment: You should edit the question and specify the version

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to achieve this with setting a attribute `minuteValues` to your input like this:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="myDate" minuteValues="0,30">
```

The `minuteValues` can be an array of numbers or a string of comma separated numbers.

**EDIT:**

Based on comment. `ion-datetime` directive is not available in Ionic 1.x but can be used in Ionic 2.x. For Ionic 1.x you can use a plugin like [ion-datetime-picker](https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am not using ionic 2. Is this possible with ionic 1 ?

Comment: Oh ok, then I don't think so. It's only integrated in Ionic 2. You need to use a plugin for Ionic 1.x